Installing GFCI with two white & 1 black wires
I am replacing a bathroom outlet with a GFCI. The old outlet has TWO BLACK wires (definitely black), ONE WHITE wire, and a grounding wire.  The white appears to be piggybacked to 2 other white wires. Not sure where to put the black wires since there is only 1 white wire. Can only find instructions when there are two white and 1 black. FYI, there is a light switch & exhaust fan in the room but neither are on the same breaker.



One black is power(line) and the other black(load) goes to a different receptacle/light.  Not quite sure why they used a pigtail for the neutral whites, the outlet would take both whites(it looks like the whites were cut too short).  The second device will determine if you can just use line or line and load(separate and pigtail both whites) on the GFCI.

Great!! I understand everything you said, and thanks for explaining it “Barney” style that’s what I needed.  I think the “other” black is to one of the other bathrooms in the house: it appears all three bathroom outlets are on the same breaker.
Just one more thing, please.  how do I determine which line is the “line in?”

Line in will be the one that is always hot with the two blacks disconnected from each other.   A non contact voltage tester(NCVT) or a multi-meter will be needed to test.  Much safer than using your tongue.  Turn off the breaker, removed the blacks, and with them both not touching anything but air, turn on the breaker for testing.

With the power off, remove the wire nut on the 3 white wires.  Discard the "pigtail" that goes to the GFCI.
You now need to determine which cable is the "Line", ( power coming to the unit)
The black wire from that cable goes to the brass, "Hot" side marked LINE
the matching white wire from the same cable goes to the silver side for LINE.
The remaining black and white wires go to the LOAD part of the GFIC and carry the power and neutral to the next device.  It will be protected by the GFCI.
Tying the neutrals together before the GFCI is not a good idea.

Think someone goofed on cutting the neutrals too short, why the pigtail in the first place.

@crip, I hear ya, always some issue to overcome from the previous person. The neutrals can be pigtailed separately and attached to the proper screw.
